# Unexpected token "name" of value "if" ("end of statement block" expected)

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I tried to upgrade Symfony to 4.4.17 and I got the above error for the line:

`{% for lang, group in lang_groups if lang == from %}`

This is the code. I have no idea how to fix this.

```
    <div class="input-style">
        <input type="text" name="query" value="{{ query|default('') }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="select-style">
        <select name="lang_from">
            {% for lang, group in lang_groups %}
                <option value="{{ lang }}"{% if from == lang %} selected{% endif %}>{{ group.label }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="reverse-lang-pair" title="reverse language pair">&#8644;</a>
    {% for lang, group in lang_groups if lang == from %}
        <div class="select-style lang-group" data-lang="{{ lang }}">
            <select name="{{ lang }}">
                {% for lang_to, data in group.to %}
                    <option value="{{ lang_to }}"{% if to|default('') == lang_to %} selected{% endif %}>{{ data.label }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put the `if` statement out of your `for...in`

So instead of this

```
    {% for lang, group in lang_groups if lang == from %}
        <div class="select-style lang-group" data-lang="{{ lang }}">
            <select name="{{ lang }}">
                {% for lang_to, data in group.to %}
                    <option value="{{ lang_to }}"{% if to|default('') == lang_to %} selected{% endif %}>{{ data.label }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

If I understood what you are trying to do, you should do something like this:

```
{% for lang, group in lang_groups %}
  {% if lang == from %}
        <div class="select-style lang-group" data-lang="{{ lang }}">
            <select name="{{ lang }}">
                {% for lang_to, data in group.to %}
                    <option value="{{ lang_to }}"{% if to|default('') == lang_to %} selected{% endif %}>{{ data.label }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But it should work: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition

Comment: The doc you mentionned states 2 interesting things: FIrst, that you should rather use "filter" filter instead of a condition chained to a loop. Secondly, that you shouldn't put the loop variable (here, "lang") in the condition as it can generated weird cases. TL;DR: don't do that :)